# What is the role of the for-loop in this square root method?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have been working on a problem where I needed the square root of a BigInteger so copied someone else's method since Java does not have a built in method for it (not that I know of) and it worked.

***Here is the method:***

```
public static BigInteger bigIntSqRootFloor(BigInteger x)
    throws IllegalArgumentException {        
    if (x.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative argument.");
    }

    if (x .equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || x.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        return x;
    }

    BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2L);
    BigInteger y;

    for(y = x.divide(two); y.compareTo(x.divide(y)) > 0; y = ((x.divide(y)).add(y)).divide(two));
    return y;
}
```

However, I think the for-loop is the most import part of the method but I've never seen a one that ends with a semi-colon and I don't know how it works. Can someone explain to me what is the role of it in this method?

Comment: It means all the code is in the fir statement and there is nothing to do in the loop. The JIT doesn't optimise x .divide(y) as a constant so it problem should be written as a more tradition loop.

Comment: In case you were wondering what the heck the loop actually does, it uses [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) of computing the square root through repeated approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an empty for loop - i.e. all the logic is performed in the for statement, and it has no body.

```
for(y = x.divide(two); y.compareTo(x.divide(y)) > 0; y = ((x.divide(y)).add(y)).divide(two));
```

is equivalent to :

```
for(y = x.divide(two); y.compareTo(x.divide(y)) > 0; ) {
    y = ((x.divide(y)).add(y)).divide(two);
}
```

or to :

```
y = x.divide(two);
while (y.compareTo(x.divide(y)) > 0) {
    y = ((x.divide(y)).add(y)).divide(two);
}
```